# Nested subclasses in C++

Tags: c++, subclass, inner-classes

I'm trying to make a nested class which is also a subclass of its parent:

```
struct X { struct Y : public X {}; };
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be allowed in C++, as g++ produces the error

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct X'

However, my actual code has `X` as a templated class:

```
template<typename T> struct X
{ struct Y : public X {}; };
```

I get the same message, but this time it's only a warning:

> warning: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct X< T >'

My question is: why is the former case illegal, while the templated case just gives a warning?  The templated version works exactly as I would expect it to (I can create instances of `X<T>::Y`, cast them to `X<T>`, and so on), but does the warning mean that I shouldn't use it?  What problems can I expect to run into if I ignore the warning?

Comment: I suspect you'll get an error in the second case, too, when you try to actually instantiate `X`

Comment: Use a forward declaration of X?

Comment: @LiMuBei, you can't inherit from an incomplete (which a forwarded class is) class. that's the problem.

Comment: Answering a question you haven't asked. This is how you make it work, if you still want to: `struct X { struct Y; }; struct X::Y : public X {};` Adapting this for a template is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The language definition does not distinguish between a "warning" and an "error". The rule is that when the compiler encounters something that's illegal (loosely speaking) it must **issue a diagnostic**. Having done that, it's free to continue to compile the code, perhaps by giving the illegal construct a compiler-specific meaning. There is no requirement that a compiler refuse to compile something that does not meet the requirements of the standard (except for a `#error` preprocessor directive).

Comment: @PeteBecker but the compiler may also warn about things that are allowed by the standard. Is the latter case here allowed by the standard or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, as far as the compiler is concerned, the layout of the base (`X`) does not need to be known until the template (`X`) is instanciated. And the template (`X`) may not be istantiated before it is fully defined. At which point, it's layout is known.

Simplest way to get an error from your template is to try istantiate `Y` inside `X`:

```
template<typename T> struct X {
    struct Y : public X {};
    Y y;
};
```

In earlier versions of the complier, there was no warning in the case that you show, but it was added at some point. Here is a discussion from the [GCC bugtracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54055) about whether the warning is spurious. There were some uncertainty whether this is allowed by the standard but their conclusion was that it is not allowed.

So, neither case is allowed by the standard, but GCC keeps working with the latter, because it can.

Yam Marcovic Shows how `X::Y` can be defined in a standard compliant way. Analoguously identical example is shown in the gcc bugtracker.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the basic question: You get a warning because the template isn't yet instantiated, so it doesn't bother anyone.

The way to fix this, in both cases, would be to define `X::Y` at the point in which `X`'s layout is already known, and thus `Y`'s layout can be properly deduced. You could do:

```
struct X { struct Y; }
struct X::Y {};
```